# how to use StrSubstitutor for nested Map in java

Tags: java, dictionary

```
    Map<String, Object> baseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    baseMap.put("Name", "Raja");

    Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    address.put("Street", "RAMA");

    baseMap.put("Address", address);

    StrSubstitutor strsub = new StrSubstitutor(baseMap);

    String str = "This is ${Name} from ${Address.Street}";

    System.out.println(strsub.replace(str));
```

output is:

This is Raja from ${Address.Street}

and what I need is:

This is Raja from RAMA

How could I get this?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you need another `StrSubstitutor` instance, which replaces the `address`:

```
StrSubstitutor strsub = new StrSubstitutor(baseMap);
StrSubstitutor baseSub = new StrSubstitutor(address);

String str = "This is ${Name} from ${Address.Street}";

System.out.println(baseSub.replace(strsub.replace(str)));
```

but the better solution, I believe, would be to use a sinlge `baseMap`:

```
Map<String, Object> baseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

baseMap.put("Name", "Raja");
baseMap.put("Street", "RAMA");

StrSubstitutor strsub = new StrSubstitutor(baseMap);

String str = "This is ${Name} from ${Address.Street}";

System.out.println(strsub.replace(str));
```